# Kernel Launch Failure

Tags: cuda, runtime-error, reduce

I'm operating on a Linux system and a Tesla C2075 machine. I am launching a kernel that is a modified version of the reduction kernel. My aim is to find the mean and a step by step averaged version(time_avg) of a large data set (result). See code below.

Size of "result" and "time_avg" is same and equal to "nsamps". "time_avg" contains successive averaged sets of the array result. So, first half contains averages of every two non-overlapping samples, the quarter after that has averages of every four non-overlapping samples, the next eighth of 8 samples and so on.

```
__global__ void timeavg_mean(float *result, unsigned int *nsamps, float *time_avg, float *mean) {

__shared__ float temp[1024];
int ltid = threadIdx.x, gtid = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x, stride;
int start = 0, index;
unsigned int npts = *nsamps;

printf("here here\n");

// Store chunk of memory=2*blockDim.x (which is to be reduced) into shared memory
if ( (2*gtid) < npts ){
        temp[2*ltid] = result[2*gtid];
        temp[2*ltid+1] = result[2*gtid + 1]; 
}    
        for (stride=1; stride<blockDim.x; stride>>=1) {
                __syncthreads();
                if (ltid % (stride*2) == 0){ 
                  if ( (2*gtid) < npts ){
                        temp[2*ltid] += temp[2*ltid + stride];
                        index = (int)(start + gtid/stride);
                        time_avg[index] = (float)( temp[2*ltid]/(2.0*stride) );
                  }   
                }   
        start += npts/(2*stride);
        }   
__syncthreads();
if (ltid == 0)
{
        atomicAdd(mean, temp[0]);    
}
__syncthreads();
printf("%f\n", *mean);
}
```

Launch configuration is 40 blocks, 512 threads. Data set is ~40k samples.

In my main code, I call `cudaGetLastError()` after the kernel call and it returns no error. Memory allocations and memory copies return no errors. If I write `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` (or a `cudaMemcpy` to check for the value of mean) after the kernel call, the program hangs completely after the kernel call. If I remove it, program runs and exits. In neither case, do I get the outputs "here here" or the mean value printed. I understand that unless the kernel executes successfully, the printf's won't print. 
Has this got to do with `__syncthreads()` in a recursion? All threads will go till the same depth so I think that checks out.

What is the problem here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A kernel call is asynchronous, if the kernel starts successfully your host code will continue to run and you will see no error. Errors that happen during the kernel run appear only after you do an explicit synchronization or call a function that causes an implicit synchronization.
If your host hangs on synchronization than your kernel probably didn't finished running - it is either running some infinite loop or it is waiting on some `__synchthreads()` or some other synchronization primitive.
Your code  seems to contain an infinite loop: `for (stride=1; stride<blockDim.x; stride>>=1)`. You probably want to shift the stride left not right: `stride<<=1`.

You mentioned recursion but your code contains only one `__global__` function, there are no recursive calls.

Comment: Okay, I didn't realize that was an infinite loop. Thank you! How exactly do the operators ">>=" and "<<=" work?
I agree with your point on synchronization. But if such a situation occurs, what is the best way to debug? Using cuda-gdb, can we step into a kernel?
The function timeavg_mean is called recursively (722 times) in the main code operating on different 40k sample sets each time. But these calls are (As of now) within the same stream.

Comment: Bit-wise shift operators shift the bits left or right. Because more significant bits are located on the left side, shifting left means multiplying the value by two, shifting right means dividing by two.

Comment: You can use cuda debugger to debug a kernel, you can set a breakpoint inside a kernel and do the usual debugging stuff (step in/out/over, inspect variables etc.).

Comment: Recursive call is a call where a function calls itself (directly or indirectly). What you describe is a normal function call inside a loop.

Comment: Right, I forgot. Thanks!
The code is now running and terminating but the value for the mean that I get is wrong. Any idea why? I am only adding the values here, so I check the mean value after dividing by the number of samples. It is not wrong by an order of magnitude but is less by ~20% than the expected.

Answer (score 1):

Your kernel has an infinite loop. Replace the for loop with

```
for (stride=1; stride<blockDim.x; stride<<=1) {
```